# In Microsoft Office online, how do I hide the contacts/skype bar on the right?

Tags: skype-for-web, office-online, onenote

I'm using OneNote Online and after a couple of minutes a fat contacts list shows up on the right showing all of my Skype contacts and their various online states, etc. I have no interest in "collaborating" - it's not relevant to my current workflow, and the list of contacts both takes up screen real estate and is distracting. Its presence to the right of my note-taking is making me feel... irritated...

Is there any way to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote directly from the [Microsoft Community Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/omessaging-oim/turn-off-messaging-on-onedrive-web-interface/fa44dcb9-adb9-46e8-9d61-181d93166f6f):

"please be informed that this is not possible since it is by design that Skype is already integrated in the Web Messenger."

I don't know if it will resolve the issue, but you can try [unlinking your Skype and Microsoft accounts](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12211/how-do-i-unlink-my-skype-and-microsoft-or-facebook-accounts).